# Hibernation with systemd no longer working after enlarging swapfile

Tags: hibernate

I've created a larger swapfile on ubuntu 18.04. But now hiberation no longer works.

I do see some  remarks about a swap containing software suspend:

```
okt 14 10:06:26 hvdb-ThinkPad-T480s swapon[349]: swapon: /swapfile: software suspend data detected. Rewriting the swap signature.
```

But it simply boots normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably changed the physical location of the swapfile on disk when you enlarged it. In fact, you probably made a new file altogether, and not simply added to the end

During boot it needs that exact location to stream the suspend image to memory.

Find the location of the swapfile with `swap-offset` which is in the `uswsusp` package. Then

```
$ sudo swap-offset /swapfile
```

Use the number in the output of the above command and fill it in `/etc/default/grub` after the 'resume=' key in the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` variable.

Afterwards,make grub aware of the change by doing:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```